# If statement doesn't work / Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't why my website doesn't go through the if statement. The objective is to display an image when I click a button, but it gets stuck. If anyone could help I would be very happy :D

```
function showllum() {
        $.get('llum.txt', function(data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data === "Llum") {
                    alert("1");
                    $('#showdada').empty();
                    $('#showdada').prepend($('<img>', {
                            id: 'llumpng',
                            src: 'llum.png'
                        }

                    ))
            } else if (data === "Molta Llum") {
                    alert("2");
                    $('#showdada').empty();
                    $('#showdada').prepend($('<img>', {
                            id: 'moltallumpng',
                            src: 'molta llum.png'
                        }

                    ))

                } else if (data === "Poca Llum") {
                        alert("3");
                        $('#showdada').empty();
                        $('#showdada').prepend($('<img>', {
                                id: 'pocallumpng',
                                src: 'poca llum.png'
                            }

                        ))

                    } else if (data === "Fosques") {
                            alert("4");
                            $('#showdada').empty();
                            $('#showdada').prepend($('<img>', {
                                    id: 'fosquespng',
                                    src: 'fosques.png'
                                }

                            ))

                        }})}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185995/discussion-on-question-by-roger-marco-hernandez-if-statement-doesnt-work-java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the carriage return in the string that was causing the original problem (which is fixed with `data.trim()`), your code can be simplified since there's a pattern to your logic - each case clears the `showdada` element and then prepends an image using the pattern `` src = `${data.trim()}.png` `` in lowercase and then the `id` removes all spaces and periods from the `src`:

```
function showllum() {
  $.get('llum.txt', function(data) {
    $('#showdada').empty();
    const src = `${data.trim()}.png`.toLowerCase();
    $('#showdada').prepend($('<img>', {
      id: src.replace(/[ .]/g,''),
      src
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: 1.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: data.trim(...).toLoweeCase is not a function
    at Object.success (1.js:16)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Comment: that's a typo I fixed - `toLoweeCase` -> `toLowerCase`

Comment: also make sure the `/g` is in the regex - I forgot it in the original post

Comment: Man, literally, you saved my final course project <3, if there's any way I could give you reputation or some kinda thing tell me :D.

Comment: It may sound exaggerated, but when you spend your hours with an error that is quite impossible for you to resolve and someone helps you, seriously <3

Comment: The basic error was that data was returned with spaces, so:

Comment: 1     2 is not equal to 12

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a dataType - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "helloworld.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            if(data === '*'){...}
        }
    });
});
```

But even if you change to this, you won't get results from a localdrive, you'll need an actual http server to serve the static textfile. Please check the network requests and update here what response you get.

Comment: `$.get` doesn't need a `dataType` - test with `$.get('https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt', data => console.log(data))`

Comment: My bad, thought he used the ajax call.